# Updating to SSRS 2008R2 from 2008 messed with report pagination

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, pagination, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

We have an application which produces a multi-categorical report as a PDF. Running SSRS 2008, the reports worked as designed. After upgrading SSRS to 2008R2, the pagination seemed to have changed.

The first page appears as designed, but when a category exceeds a single page, the page break occurs in the middle of a row header. Whats more is that the page's header/footer will only appear on the first page of a multi-page category.

What I've found in research is that there were many changes to pagination in SSRS 2008 from earlier versions. But going from 2008 to 2008R2, I've found little concerning page breaks or pagination.

What is causing these problems?
What can I do to get the reports working as designed? (With headers/footers on every page, and page breaks occurring after row headers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long couple of weeks trying to solve the problem within the .rdl files, we opened a ticket with Microsoft.

Turns out that this is a known issue with some reports in SSRS 2008 R2 that is **resolved by applying Service Pack 2.**